# How to make smaller space between 2 sentences in HTML

Tags: html, css

Im working on a code and I would like to make the space between "Szafranowka" and "Apartaments & Restaurant" smaller. Here's how it looks like now: https://gyazo.com/d6843d8857e954acbae5c1da748c044b
I really cannot find the answer that would perfectly fit my expectations. Please, could any1 help me? :)
Also, I would like to make a small square around "Wejscie/Entrance", but when im trying to do it with the border, it looks like this: https://gyazo.com/f84fedc7a78854773b287e01ebd3a21f

Here's a part of code that im using to make a border:

```
<h5 style="border:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:#000000; padding: 1em;">Wejscie/Entrance</h5>
```

and here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>

<title>Szafranowka - Apartments & Restaurant </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<!-- Główny DIV całej strony -->
<div id="container">

    <!-- Lewa część tła strony, zamknięta w divie -->
    <div id="background"> 
    <img src="background.jpg"> </img>
    </div>

    <div id="header">
        <h2>Szafranowka</h2> <p>Apartments & Restaurant </p>
        <br></br> <h5 id="entrance">Wejscie/Entrance</h5>
    </div>



</div>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#background 
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: blur(3px);
  filter: contrast(50%);
  filter: brightness(30%);
}

#background img
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#header
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    color: #9F5F9F;
    font-size: 70px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #660055;
}
```

Comment: Try reducing the margin/padding on your `h2` tag.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks alot!

Comment: Avoid using inline `style=""` It's hard to maintain. you already own a nice stylesheet. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

to your #entrance, try this :

```
#entrance {
    width: 8rem; //or another size
    margin auto; // to center
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="header">
        <h2>Szafranowka</h2> <p>Apartments & Restaurant </p>
        <br></br> <span id="entrance">Wejscie/Entrance</span>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
h2{
margin:5px;
line-height:15px
}
#entrance{
border:1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>

<title>Szafranowka - Apartments & Restaurant </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
    body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#background 
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: blur(3px);
  filter: contrast(50%);
  filter: brightness(30%);
}

#background img
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#header
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    color: #9F5F9F;
    font-size: 70px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #660055;
}
#header h2
{
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
#entrance span
{
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Główny DIV całej strony -->
<div id="container">

    <!-- Lewa część tła strony, zamknięta w divie -->
    <div id="background"> 
    <img src="background.jpg"> </img>
    </div>

    <div id="header">
        <h2>Szafranowka</h2> <p>Apartments & Restaurant </p>
        <br></br> <h5 id="entrance"><span>Wejscie/Entrance</span></h5>
    </div>



</div>


</body>

</html>
```